# mediaelement.js (wordpress 3.2.1 plugin) - volume slider in IE9 misplaced

Tags: audio, internet-explorer-9, slider, volume, mediaelement.js

The volume slider seems to be pushed out to just beneath the audio player box.  I looked in the developer mode of IE9 and the relative offset is 26px whereas the relative offset of every other object in the audio player box is 0.

I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.